# How to keep grouped rows expanded by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kogrid

I'm new to Kogrid. By default my grid is grouped by UserRoles column. But it is showing collapsed by default. I want to keep my grid grouped and expanded by UserRoles column on a page load.

```html
<div id="rolesGrid" data-bind="koGrid:rolesGridOptions"></div>
```

Js:

```
this.rolesGrid = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.rolesGridCols = [
        { field: 'UserRole', displayName: 'User Role', width: '*'},
        { field: 'UserName', displayName: 'User Name', width: '*' },           
        { field: 'AssignedBy', displayName: 'Assigned By',width: '*' }
    ];

    this.rolesGridOptions = {
        data: this.rolesGrid,                
        columnDefs: this.rolesGridCols,
        groups: ['UserRole'],
        showGroupPanel: false,           
    };
};
```

Comment: you'll have to elaborate and maybe provide some code / jsfiddle demo please

Comment: Aziz, I added html & javascript code

Comment: Does anyone has answer to my question??

Comment: I am able to hide this element'<div data-bind="attr: { \'Class\': aggclass}", KgAggArrowCollapsed></div>' from console. How to do it in javascript? I want to hide arrow and only show text on grouped row

Comment: what happens if you make it `showGroupPanel: true` ?

Comment: i want to restrict in changing grouping columns

Comment: can you share a photo of desired effect and what you have currently?